# Dijkstra algorithm fails when calculating multiple paths

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm for multiple nodes. For example i have x amount of nodes to be visited and i need to make a route to visit each one without changing their order, it doesnt matter if there's shorter path than that. Everything seemed to work at first but after more than 2 nodes it fails at calculating route and goes out of memory. I'm assuming I did something terrible here.

I'm sorry for this unclear question, but I'm not really sure how to make it shorter.

Edit: The problem is that when there are added 3 or more Vertices in 'verticesToVisit' list, Java throws out out of memory in Java heap space exception at 'getShortestPath method, exact line is marked with comment below.

Anyways here's my classes:

```
Vertice

private List<Edge> adjencies;
private double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
private Vertice previous;

public Domicile() {
    adjencies = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    previous = null;
}
public void reset() {
    this.minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
}
// sets and gets..
```

Edge

```
private Vertice target;
private Vertice source; // Not used in algorithm, just for debugging
private double weight;

public Edge(Vertice argSource, Vertice argTarget, double argWeight) {
    source = argSource;
    target = argTarget;
    weight = argWeight;
}
public Edge(){}
// sets and gets
```

Algorithm:

```
public void computePaths(Vertice source) {
    source.setMinDistance(0.);
    PriorityQueue<Vertice> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertice>();
    vertexQueue.add(source);
    while(!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
        Vertice u = vertexQueue.poll();

        for(Edge e : u.getAdjencies()) {
            Vertice v = e.getTarget();
            double weight = e.getWeight();
            double distanceThroughU = u.getMinDistance() + weight;
            if(distanceThroughU < v.getMinDistance()) {
                vertexQueue.remove(v);
                v.setMinDistance(distanceThroughU);
                v.setPrevious(u);
                vertexQueue.add(v);
            }
        }
    }
}
///////////////////////
// This method fails //
///////////////////////
public List<Vertice> getShortestPathTo(Vertice target) {
    List<Vertice> path = new ArrayList<Vertice>();
    for(Vertice vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.getPrevious()) {
        path.add(vertex);   // Java runs out of memory "Java heap size" here
    }
    Collections.reverse(path);
    return path;
}

public void resetAllVertices() {
    for(Vertice dom : graph) {
        dom.reset();
    }
}


public List<String> getRoute() {
    List<Vertice> verticesToVisit = dbd.getAllVertice(); // Gets them from database. This part is working.
    Collections.sort(verticesToVisit);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(verticesToVisit.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    else if(patients.size() < 2) {
        result.add(verticestoVisit.get(0).getName());
    } else {

        for(int i = 0; i < verticesToVisit.size()-1; i++) {
            Vertices graphDomStart = findFromGraph(verticesToVisit.get(i).getLocationId()); // finds vertice in graph (in db they dont have edges)
            Vertice graphDomGoal = findFromGraph(verticesToVisit.get(i+1).getLocationId()); // finds vertice in graph (in db they dont have edges)

            computePaths(graphDomStart); // exception is tracked from here
            result.add(formatAddress(getShortestPathTo(graphDomGoal)));

            resetAllVertices();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private Domicile findFromGraph(int locationId) {
    for(Domicile dom : graph) {
        if(dom.getLocationId() == locationId) {
            return dom;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thank you and sorry for big wall of code.

Comment: You need to focus the question and the code to the relevant part. Is the algorithm working for 1 source- 1 target? What part of the code is suspected to be problematic. Please also provide an example showing the erroneous behavior - and the expected behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your reset function:

```
public void reset() {
    this.minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
}
```

I recommend you also reset previous

```
public void reset() {
    this.minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    this.previous = null;
}
```

or you will get an infinite loop when tracing the path backwards.

Comment: That was the whole problem, hours of frustration are over with one line fix, that's why i love programming
Thanks a lot..